# How to convert font size value in pt to sp

Tags: android, text-size

I want to set text size to my Button text. The value ii have to set is 22 pt. I want to convert it into sp.This is for XHDPI screen. How can I do this?

Comment: use this http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Comment: you are really not a newbie, and should already have learned that you have to use search before asking something.